# Check if page is a woocommerce attribute

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to figure out how to customize the attribute page (for example, if i click on a link to the "length" attribute with a term of "7 inches", wordpress will echo all products that have a length attribute with term 7. My question is, how do I customize such a page?

Hope this is clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@TimothyKA your solution might return true when you visit an attribute page however, it will return true on any taxonomy page ( and possibly it will produce PHP warnings on all the rest ).

You need to create a conditional function that returns true only when you are working on an attribute page. The following should work just fine:

```
function my_is_wc_attribute() {

    /** 
     * Attributes are proper taxonomies, therefore first thing is 
     * to check if we are on a taxonomy page using the is_tax(). 
     * Also, a further check if the taxonomy_is_product_attribute 
     * function exists is necessary, in order to ensure that this 
     * function does not produce fatal errors when the WooCommerce 
     * is not  activated
     */
    if ( is_tax() && function_exists( 'taxonomy_is_product_attribute') ) { 
        // now we know for sure that the queried object is a taxonomy
        $tax_obj = get_queried_object();
        return taxonomy_is_product_attribute( $tax_obj->taxonomy );
    }
    return false;
}
```

After adding the above function to your functions.php, you may create as many filters and actions to customize your attribute pages. For example, the following filter allows you to manipulate only the attributes title:

```
function my_single_term_title_filter( $attribute_title ) {

    if ( my_is_wc_attribute() ) {

        // do your stuff here
    }

    return $attribute_title;
}
add_filter( 'single_term_title', 'my_single_term_title_filter' );
```

Don't forget to replace the *my_* prefixes with your own prefix, to avoid function naming conflicts.

Comment: The snippet does indeed work, my question now is: where can i find the list of filters to manipulate where the code is being placed?

Comment: One of the major advantages of using WordPress is the vast amount of documentation, tutorials and general references over the internet. Since you are working with a theme, you could start from the [Templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Templates) and [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/) sections on the WordPress.org website.

Comment: okay, i'll go and look there! I'll consider this post solved since you provided a more advanced approach to my issue! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

There is a WooCommerce function for that:

```
is_product_taxonomy(); // Returns true when viewing a product taxonomy archive.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. (code below + explanation for anyone who will perhaps stumble upon this).

```
$q_object = get_queried_object();
$taxonomy = $q_object->taxonomy;

// if page has taxonomy
if ( is_tax( $taxonomy ) ) {
    echo 'THIS WORKS';
} else {
    // does not
}
```

**1.** *`get_queried_object();`* -- is used on a currently queried object such as single post, archive page, taxonomy page etc... ([link to wp codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object))

**2.** *`$q_object->taxonomy;`* -- This allows us to get the taxonomy of the queried object (see point 1.)

**3.** *`if ( is_tax( $taxonomy ) ) {`* -- Checks if page has taxonomy.

I hope my solution is clear, this is my first time trying to answer my own question and any question on stack-exchange for that matter.