# WooCommerce is_product_category() not working

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to add text to the product short description by category.

So for example, for all Cake Toppers, I want to add to the bottom of the short description to show "This is a cake topper". For all products which are not cake toppers, I want to show the text "Not a cake topper".

This is the code I'm using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_short_description_by_category', 20 );

function product_short_description_by_category() {
if( is_product_category('cake-toppers') ){
   echo '<p>A cake topper</p>';
    }else{ 
    echo '<p>NOT CAKE TOPPER</p>';
    }
}
```

But all products, including cake topper, show "THIS IS NOT A CAKE TOPPER".

What am I doing wrong here? "cake-toppers" is the slug for the category name.

Site at: http://wendyw11.sg-host.com/product/two-wild-cake-topper/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/333424/check-if-page-is-a-woocommerce-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is_product_category() – Check If Current Page is a Product Category

Try this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_short_description_by_category', 20 );

function product_short_description_by_category() { 

        if( has_term( 'cake-toppers', 'product_cat' )){ 

                echo 'A cake topper'; 
        } else{ 
                echo 'NOT CAKE TOPPER'; 
        } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Valerii, thank you, that does work! Would you mind explaining why my original code does not work?

Comment: The reason is that `is_product_category()` tells you if you're browsing a product category, not if the current product has a particular category.